# Inlining a function template specialization

Tags: c++

The following code is in a .h file (with include guards)

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> // a
void func(T1 const &t1, T2 const &t2)
{
    std::cout << "\nbase template"; 
}

template<> // b
inline void func<int, int>(int const &t1, int const &t2)
{
    std::cout << "\nspecialization for integers";
}
```

When removing the  inline keyword from (b) the following code (called from a .cpp that includes the .h) won't compile

```
func<int, int>(1, 2);
```

emmiting a linker error " error LNK2005: "void __cdecl func(int const &,int const &)" (??$func@HH@@YAXABH0@Z) already defined in ConsoleApplication1.obj "

Why is this happening ?

EDIT:

So since they are definitions (answered by Luchian Grigore), do explicit specializations imply explicit instantiation or is this compiler specific?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because explicit specializations are definitions and so including that file in multiple translation units results in defining the symbol multiple times, which breaks the one definition rule.

Besides marking it `inline`, you can leave the declaration in the header and move the definition to an implementation file.

Comment: Thnx for the alternative to inline!

Answer (score 2):

You can only overloade it directly with the type itself, without the need to write template :

```
void func(int const &t1, int const &t2)
{
    std::cout << "\nspecialization for integers";
}
```

Now, the error happens because that function if defined in a header can end up in two cpp files if the header is included so there will be two declaration of the same function (like the error says: `already defined` ) causing a linking error. To solve this just write the declaration in the header without the implementation and move the implementation in one of the header files:

```
//header
void func(int const &t1, int const &t2);

//cpp file
void func(int const &t1, int const &t2)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Function templates can be specialized explicitly, you shouldn't but you can (http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) and it's essentially different from overloading (please refer to the link and reconsider your answer)